# From EXCEL to XSD generated class in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialization, xsd, xml-deserialization

I have this situation, I have been provided with an XSD schema consisting of four XSD files which I was able to convert to a class using the XSD.exe tool and include it in my project, for this example this class is named "Test_XSD".  On the other side I have a populated excel sheet table consisting of 10 columns which I need to map to certain elements in the "Text XSD".  The "Test_XSD" schema is complex however if I map the 10 columns to their relevant elements is sufficient since many other elements are not mandatory.  I have searched and searched but cannot find a simple example to start building on it.

I am able to read the excel file in Visual Studio and convert to XML, however this does not conform with the XSD generated class.  I know that I have to create an instance of the "Test_XSD" and load it with the data from the Excel but I don't have any clue from where to start.  Can someone explain what needs to be done.

This is what I've done so far, not too much I admit but this is something totally new for me and to be honest I didn't have yet understood the way forward although I've researched a lot.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Using an OleDbConnection to connect to excel
        var cs = $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={@"C:\AAAA\Report.xlsx"};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = Yes; IMEX = 2"";Persist Security Info=False";
        var con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
        con.Open();

    // Using OleDbCommand to read data of the sheet(sheetName)
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand($"select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    //// Convert DataSet to Xml
    //using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\MT2362\Downloads\CRS_XML.xml", FileMode.CreateNew))
    //{
    //    using (var xw = new XmlTextWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
    //    {
    //        ds.WriteXml(xw);
    //    }
    //}

    XSD xsd = new XSD();
    xsd.version = "TEST VERSION";

    Console.WriteLine(xsd.version);
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

I've noted taht the class generated from the XSD ("Test_XSD") is composed of multiple partial class, hence I think that an instance for each class must be created.

Thanks in advance, code snippets are highly appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you provided some code to show what you have tried in order to get some context and give more guided feedback.

Comment: Are you trying to take data from the Excel worksheet and output it as XML according to the schema?

Comment: It's possible that you might create classes using xsd.exe, add some custom code, and then need to re-generate the classes because of a small schema change. That's why they are generated as partial classes. It allows you to put your custom code in a separate file which won't get wiped out if you need to re-generate the class from the schema.

Comment: @Scott Hannen, yes that what i'm trying to do but the class generated from the XSD (using XSD.exe tool) is quite complex and I'do not know how to populate the object in this class.

Comment: can you please post: (i) example of some source data?

Answer (score 0):

The object of your XSD class would have public properties. If you set the value of these properties (similar to your .version in your example), then your object is fully populated.

Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

After running the XSD.exe tool, the output would be a list of C# classes that would be available to you.

Since you were able to successfully read from the Excel file and create and XML file for the dataset.

Perform the following:

1. Add a new class to your project as follows:

   ```
   public class ExcelNameSpaceXmlTextReader : XmlTextReader
   {          

        public ExcelNameSpaceXmlTextReader(System.IO.TextReader reader)
           : base(reader) { }

       public override string NamespaceURI
       {
           get { return ""; }
       }
   }
   ```

Then in a separate Utitlity class add a deserializer function as follows

```
public class Utility
{

        public T FromXml<T>(String xml)
        {
            T returnedXmlClass = default(T);

            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {                
               returnedXmlClass = (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(new ExcelNameSpaceXmlTextReader(reader)); 
            } 


        return returnedXmlClass;
    }

}
```

Now add code to consume the read in data from XML as the object you want to serialize the data to by consuming the generic Utility function

So your code would be like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Using an OleDbConnection to connect to excel
    var cs = $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={@"C:\AAAA\Report.xlsx"};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = Yes; IMEX = 2"";Persist Security Info=False";
    var con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
    con.Open();

// Using OleDbCommand to read data of the sheet(sheetName)
var cmd = new OleDbCommand($"select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
var ds = new DataSet();
var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);

   // Convert DataSet to Xml
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\MT2362\Downloads\CRS_XML.xml", FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (var xw = new XmlTextWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        ds.WriteXml(xw);
    }
}

     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\Users\MT2362\Downloads\CRS_XML.xml");

Test_XSD test_XSD = Utility.FromXml<Test_XSD>(doc.Document.ToString()); 

XSD xsd = new XSD();
xsd.version = "TEST VERSION";

Console.WriteLine(xsd.version);
Console.ReadKey();

}
```